# Drawing attention to rows below the fold on a list

Tags: lists, scrolling, indicator, user-attention

I'm designing a feature that highlights certain users on a list. For this i'm considering using an (!) icon.

However, the list is long and requires scrolling. there will be users below the fold that also need to be highlighted. the challenge is how do we make the user know that there are users that need attention below the fold.

I've come up with 1 solution, but it might not be the best. Feel free to suggestion new solutions or how i could improve this.

[image]

Comment: Are users scrolling just in a specific frame, or are they scrolling the whole page?

Answer (score 2):

That makes sense. Here are some minor tweaks...

Make the indicator look more like a pointer than a bubble:

[image: pointer]

And make it a circle to harmonize with the flag it's indicating there are more of:

[image: circle pointer]

Also giving more room for the indicator so it doesn't hide any flags in the last visible row.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create another column with a filter for easy exploration/grouping and maybe mass actions. Hard to design the best solution without more informations ...

[image]